# Installing "cryptography" on Python 3.9.0a5 (error)

Tags: python, pip, openssl, python-cryptography, python-3.9

just updated Python from 3.8.2 to 3.9.0a5 due to the merge operator for dictionaries.
When I now try to install "cryptography" in my virtual environment, I get the following error:

[cryptography install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8xbl.png)

Pip Version is: 20.1.1,
Python Version is: 3.9.0a5

Comment: You installed an alpha version (**a** in 3.9.0**a**5 is for alpha). I believe the latest (as of writing this comment) is beta 3 (Python 3.9.0b3) so try with that. However, keep in mind that a beta version does not guarantee everything will work, that's why it's a beta.

Answer (score 3):

This package does not publish a wheel (precompiled) version for python 3.9 only up to 3.8

https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/2.9.2/#files

so this means that you will need to install the headers into your computer's build environment so that python can compile with openssl from source (on some linux systems that will be as simple as installing a package with the openssl headers and library, on windows you may also need to install a c compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! With your Instructions I was able to figure out the remaining steps.
Installing latest SSL for 64bit and setting env variables properly with:

```
set LIB=C:\OpenSSL-win64\lib;%LIB%
set INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-win64\include;%INCLUDE%
```

fixed the issue :)